# For two-factor authentication is it a security issue to have phone authentication and Google Titan Security Key?

Tags: multi-factor, google

I am trying to setup my Google account to have some proper security.  But I'm finding parts of it confusing.  I used to just use my phone as my 2FA device.  Where I would get a texted code.  Then I read about how someone could intercept that and that it wasn't a good method.  Then I bought a Google Titan Security key.  My google account allows me to add my phone and Titan key.  But should I disable the phone for the reason mention above? Thanks!

Comment: To avoid SIM swap attacks you do need to disable phone authentication. SIM swap attacks tend to be targeted attacks against high value targets. So up to you if you think that's an important threat for you in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Your threat model may be different from other people's, but generally speaking, if you have hardware keys but SMS can still be used to reset access, then SMS is the "weakest link in the chain" and could be exploited.

You could disable SMS to mitigate this. Google offers a pre-configured approach to move to require only strong second factors, called [the Advanced Protection Program](https://landing.google.com/advancedprotection/). In this approach, after you provide two hardware security keys, all other authentication methods are automatically disabled. Note that this makes it harder to reset your access if you ever need to - that's the tradeoff. To mitigate some of that risk, you can add a third key (or even more), and keep alternate keys in safe locations.